# Scaffolding Controllers and Views for Orchard

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have a Fluent nHibernate data tier that I would like to use in an Orchard Module. This data tier currently serves an MVC3 project but my Controllers/Views have way too much learning curve crap embedded to think they are worth salvaging.

I'd like to understand exactly how i should go about code-genning a set of CRUD for an MVC3 project that will be used inside Orchard 1.0.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orchard won't give you that much added value on scaffolding CRUD stuff, except if the data in question fits well into the Orchard model for extensible contents. In that case, following one of the tutorials on how to create parts should be helpful.
This being said, if you want to just integrate your existing MVC3 work into Orchard, make that an area, move the routes into Route.cs and add a module.txt manifest, and you're pretty much done (the hello world module tutorial explains some of that).
I hope this helps.

Comment: Regarding the '...fits well into extensible contents...' In that i'm standing most to gain by tying into the CM part of the S, it might be best for me to bend my model to Orchard. But seems like not much activity in the ecommerce/shopping cart side of things. But to bring the question  back to scaffolding... I've watched Sanderson's but can't separate the 'EF' from the mvcScaffoling.  [btw, i've clicked the 'save as answer' twice already and it seems still to be un checked.]